# How can I make the if statement here check for integer numbers?

Tags: c++11

I would like only integer inputs for month and day so that it gives an error message when one uses a decimal number. How can I do that in this code? I have looked on line but I can't understand what I am looking at.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int month, day;

cout << "Enter a month (use 1 for Jan, etc.): ";    
cin >> month;
if (month<1 || month>12)
    cout << "Invalid month entered\n";

cout << "Enter a day of the month: ";
cin >> day;
if (day<1 || day>31)
    cout << "Invalid day entered\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Read an input using `getline` into a string.  Then test whether the string can be converted to an integer.  If yes, great.  If not, there was input, but it was either non-numeric or contained a decimal point.

Comment: Sorry but how would I implement that? I am new to c++ programming. I just need pointers. You don't have to give me the whole code.